# Java 8 Streams reduce remove duplicates keeping the most recent entry

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, reduction

I have a Java bean, like

```
class EmployeeContract {
    Long id;
    Date date;
    getter/setter
}
```

If a have a long list of these, in which we have duplicates by id but with different date, such as:

```
1, 2015/07/07
1, 2018/07/08
2, 2015/07/08
2, 2018/07/09
```

How can I reduce such a list keeping only the entries with the most recent date, such as:

```
1, 2018/07/08
2, 2018/07/09
```

?
Preferably using Java 8...

I've started with something like:

```
contract.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeContract::getId, Collectors.mapping(EmployeeContract::getId, Collectors.toList())))
                    .entrySet().stream().findFirst();
```

That gives me the mapping within individual groups, but I'm stuck as to how to collect that into a result list - my streams are not too strong I'm afraid...

Comment: I wanted to post an answer but this one was closed too fast... `yourList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        EmployeeContract::getId,
                        Function.identity(),
                        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(EmployeeContract::getDate).reversed()))
                )
                .values();`

Comment: @Eugene instead of `BinaryOperator.maxBy( … .reversed())`, you can use `BinaryOperator.minBy(…)`. Though in this case, it looks like the OP wants `maxBy`, without `.reversed()`.

Comment: @Holger and given that this(`values()`) would return a `Collection<EmployeeContract>` and not precisely a `List<EmployeeContract>`, is there a concise way to resolve that?

Comment: Given there is a valid discussion and it's a bona fide quiestion, perhaps it's worth to un-hold this question?

Comment: @Holger indeed...

Comment: @nullpointer if it really needs to be a `List`, you can a) wrap the entire expression in a `new ArrayList<>( … )` or b) wrap the collector in a `Collectors.collectingAndThen( …, m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values()))`.

Comment: Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Never use `Date` (a terrible class, now legacy).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I am just going to put my comment here in the shape of an answer:

```
 yourList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  EmployeeContract::getId,
                  Function.identity(),
                  BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(EmployeeContract::getDate)))
            )
         .values();
```

This will give you a `Collection` instead of a `List`, if you really care about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps as follows :

```
List<EmployeeContract> finalContract = contract.stream() // Stream<EmployeeContract>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(EmployeeContract::getId, 
                EmployeeContract::getDate, (a, b) -> a.after(b) ? a : b)) // Map<Long, Date> (Step 1)
        .entrySet().stream() // Stream<Entry<Long, Date>>
        .map(a -> new EmployeeContract(a.getKey(), a.getValue())) // Stream<EmployeeContract>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Step 2
```

*First step*:  ensures the comparison of `date`s with the most recent one mapped to an `id`.

*Second step*: maps these key, value pairs to a final `List<EmployeeContract>` as a result.

Comment: why `(a, b) -> a.after(b) ? a : b)` when `Date` already implement `Comparable`?

Comment: no specific reason @Eugene, I was just looking into the `Date` API for comparison and found using `after` a little better in terms of readability.

Comment: Good answer, and with step-by step explanation, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the existing answers, as you're asking:

> how to collect that into a result list

Here are some options:

- Wrap the `values()` into an `ArrayList`:

  ```
  List<EmployeeContract> list1 = 
      new ArrayList<>(list.stream()            
                          .collect(toMap(EmployeeContract::getId,                                                                          
                                         identity(),
                                         maxBy(comparing(EmployeeContract::getDate))))
                          .values());
  ```
- Wrap the `toMap` collector into `collectingAndThen`:

  ```
  List<EmployeeContract> list2 = 
      list.stream()
          .collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(EmployeeContract::getId,
                                           identity(),
                                           maxBy(comparing(EmployeeContract::getDate))),
                   c -> new ArrayList<>(c.values())));
  ```
- Collect the `values` to a new `List` using another stream:

  ```
  List<EmployeeContract> list3 = 
      list.stream()
          .collect(toMap(EmployeeContract::getId,
                         identity(),
                         maxBy(comparing(EmployeeContract::getDate))))
          .values()
          .stream()
          .collect(toList());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

With [vavr.io](http://www.vavr.io/) you can do it like this:

```
var finalContract = Stream.ofAll(contract) //create io.vavr.collection.Stream
            .groupBy(EmployeeContract::getId)
            .map(tuple -> tuple._2.maxBy(EmployeeContract::getDate))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); //result is list from java.util package
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the difference with a classic Stream from java.util.stream ?

Comment: in io.vavr collections objects are immutable and they have map(), filter() etc methods